# Projection onto union of two affine subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, orthogonality

Let $\ C_1=\{\ x\in {R^n} \ |\  \langle u,x\rangle\leq\alpha\ \}\ $ and $\ C_2=\{\ x\in {R^n} \ |\  \langle u,x\rangle\leq\beta\ \}. $
Give the orthogonal projection of $x\in{R^n}$ onto $\ C_1\cup C_2.$

Answer (score 0):

Without losing generality we can assume $\alpha \ge \beta$, then $C_1 \supseteq C_2$, if $x\in C_1$ then the projection is $x$ itself, and we have finished. If $x\notin C_1$ the vector $u$ is perpendicular to the plane that delimits $C_1$, can you guess any operation involving $x$ and $u$ that lets you translate $x$ on the plane that delimits $C_1$?